# How to define type for object in graphql schema?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I have todo's mongo schema like this:

```
const todoSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: String, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    due_date: {
      date: { type: Number },
      month: { type: Number },
      year: { type: Number },
      hours: { type: Number },
      minute: { type: Number },
    },
    status: { type: String, required: true},
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

I wanna make graphql schema so I did like this:

```
const Todo = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Todo",
  fields: () => ({
    _id: { type: GraphQLID },
    userId: { type: GraphQLString },
    title: { type: GraphQLString },
    due_date: { type: GraphQLString },
    status: { type: GraphQLString },
  })
});
```

So my question is what is the correct type for due date? In mongo I defined it as an object and how can I define the due_date as an object in graphql schema?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use either the [DateTime](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/scalars/docs/scalars/date-time) or [Date](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/scalars/docs/scalars/date) type from the graphql-scalars package depending on your specific needs.

Furthermore, in GraphQL models foreign keys are rarely included in a type. Instead a reference is made directly to the type.

```
type Todo {
  _id: ID!
  user: User
  title: String
  due_date: Date
  status: String
}
```

If `status` is from a finite list of values then you'll want to define an `enum` for it and then refer to that enum.